# Is it possible to declare a weak function by passing an argument to gcc?

Tags: c, compilation, linker, weak-references

We can declare weak function by using `__attribute__((weak))` in C code files. I wonder if there exists a way to declare this during compile time from gcc and not write anything in the code files?

For e.g.

File: foo.h

```
int foo();
```

File: foo.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int foo(){
   printf("foo called from file\n");
   return 1;
}
```

File: main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"foo.h"
int foo(){
  printf("foo called from main");
  return 1;
} 

int main(){
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

**Is it possible to compile above code and export foo as weak from command line?**

E.g. `gcc --weak=foo.c:foo foo.c main.c`

`./a.out produces foo called from main.`

I know that writing`__attribute__((weak))` above `foo()` declaration in `foo.c` will call `foo()` in main.

The blog:

blog.microjoe.org/2017/unit-tests-c-cmocka-coverage-cmake.html

says that it is possible to do so....

> There are two ways of declaring a weak symbol:
>
> 1. By passing an argument to GCC, telling it to export the symbol of this function as a weak symbol.
> 2. By putting a **attribute**((weak)) annotation before the function implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no, there is no such option.

This sounds a little bit like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), perhaps you should state more clearly what problem you are trying to solve, instead of which solution you want to make work.

As an aside, your example would not work, since you're providing two definitions and not saying *which* one should be considered weak. It would have to be

```
# Remember this doesn't really work!
$ gcc --weak=foo.c:foo foo.c main.c
```

or something, i.e. you need to indicate in which file the weak definition resides.

Comment: I'm using cmocka tool for writing unit tests where in I create mock functions by redefining the function body in my test file. In order to do this, I'm declaring the function as a weak function. E.g.
application.c contains function foo() which is declared as weak. test_application.c also has a foo() which no implementation [mock of foo() from application.c] and main() from test_application.c initiates unit test on foo() from application.c

I don't want to declare/show-case that my function in application file is a weak. Passing from command line would allow me to achieve this.

Comment: The blog: https://blog.microjoe.org/2017/unit-tests-c-cmocka-coverage-cmake.html
says that it is possible to do so....


""" There are two ways of declaring a weak symbol:

By passing an argument to GCC, telling it to export the symbol of this function as a weak symbol.
By putting a __attribute__((weak)) annotation before the function implementation.
"""

Comment: @VasuMistry I would suggest a macro like the blog post. Note that it doesn't say how this is done with GCC, only that it can be done. It might be correct, I am at least not able to find proof though.

Comment: It says using a DEBUG macro, how to use it? Is it an integer with shared state? Basically how to toggle DEBUG on and off?

Comment: @VasuMistry It also says that solution is not so good, that it would be better with a `TESTING` macro, which is then `#defined` to be the relevant `attribute` in the proper build, from the Makefile or equivalent.